# Laravel Ajax - success executed even when db row is not present

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm working on a project where I have some jQuery code that is supposed to check if a certain row in the database exists. If the row does exist, The code within the success stage gets executed. But the problem I have with this script is when the 'checkdb' function gets executed the code within success happens even though the row doesn't exist in the database. What is causing this?

**jQuery code**

```
 checkdb = function () {
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/droplet/get/' + {{ $webshop->id }},
            data: '_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',

            success: function(data) {

                var id = setInterval(frame, 500);

                function frame() {
                    console.log('Executing "Frame"');
                    if (width2 >= 30) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                        clearInterval(mainInterval);

                        installWebshop();
                        alert('This is done');
                    } else {
                        width2++;
                        elements(width2);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Something went wrong' . data);
            }
        });
        console.log('Executing "checkDB"');
    };
    mainInterval = setInterval(checkdb,1000 * 60);
```

The jQuery above gets executed every minute, To check if the row is present.
The PHP code below is supposed to check if the row in the database exists. If it does, it should return a response which then ends up in the succeeding stage in jQUery. If it does not already exist, Do something else

**PHP code**

```
public function getAll(Request $request, $id)
{
    $droplet = Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $id)->exists();

    if ($droplet != null) {

        $info = Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $id)->get();

        return response()->json(array($info));

    } else {

        return response()->json('There is nothing');
    }

}
```

Why is it executing the succeeding stage even though the row does not already exist? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing `$droplet = Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $id)->exists();` to `$droplet = Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $id)->first();`

Comment: i believe `exists()` returns true or false, so you're checking for `null`, instead check for `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
response('content', 200, $headers)  and `json()` helper also takes three param `json($data, status, $headers)`
```

methods take three parameters replace the content of the else

like

```
public function getAll(Request $request, $id)
{
    $droplet = Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $id)->exists();

    if ($droplet != null) {

        $info = Droplet::where("webshop_id", "=", $id)->get();

        return response()->json(array($info));

    } else {

        return response()->json('There is nothing',404);
    }

}
```

In jQuery, **success** block gets executed when response status code is 200. If you send status code as 404 which is in else block when DB is not exist, then **error** block will get executed instead of success. Laravel by default will send 200 as status code for AJAX requests in response.

Answer (score 0):

Add dataType:"JSON"

```
checkdb = function () {
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/droplet/get/' + {{ $webshop->id }},
        data: '_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
        datatype:'JSON',
        success: function(data) {

            var id = setInterval(frame, 500);

            function frame() {
                console.log('Executing "Frame"');
                if (width2 >= 30) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    clearInterval(mainInterval);

                    installWebshop();
                    alert('This is done');
                } else {
                    width2++;
                    elements(width2);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('Something went wrong' . data);
        }
    });
    console.log('Executing "checkDB"');
};
mainInterval = setInterval(checkdb,1000 * 60);
```